# How do I couple dependent git repositories?

Tags: git

I have a desktop application with a supporting web service. Conceptually, they are distinct, so belong in separate git repositories.

How can I tie the two together so that when I return to an older version of the application, I am able to retrieve the correct version of its associated web service?

Comment: Try adding the web service as a 'Submodule'

Comment: @Tom - Thanks for the reply. I did consider this, but most developers on the application would never need access to the web service. It seems like a lot of overhead.

Comment: You could Tag both repositories with the same version tag as part of each release? That way developers can only worry about the repo they care about, but you can still tell which versions correspond to each other.

Comment: submodule is the right way. The developers _will_ need the web service since the versions need to match. no point in having the desktop application at an earlier version w/o the matching backend service setup w/ the matching version.